# Stop table from adding decimal places

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to display a frequency table using Shiny in R, but for some reason it insists on showing the frequency to two decimal places. I've tried using round(), but this isn't having any impact. I'm guessing it might be to do with the merge, because when I back up and just display the frequency table, the frequency is shown without unnecessary decimal places...but I'm not sure which exact part is causing the problem, which is why I'm including pretty much all elements of wrangling I do to the code in this example. You need to search for one of the fruits (e.g. apple) to get the table to display and see what I mean.

Thanks for your help!

What it looks like now: 
[image: Current view]

```
library("shiny")
library("shinydashboard")

fruit <- as.character(c("apple", "pineapple", 
                        "orange", "watermelon", "apple", 
                        "grape", "orange", "apple", "grape"))

fruit_type <- as.character(c("apple", "pineapple", "orange", "watermelon", "grape", "banana", "coconut"))
fruit_rating <- 1:7
fruit_info <- data.frame(fruit_type, fruit_rating, stringsAsFactors = F)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(searchInput("search",
                                        btnSearch = icon("search"), 
                                        btnReset = icon("remove")))

body <- dashboardBody(tableOutput("table"))

ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "Example"),
                    sidebar,
                    body
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- renderTable({
    fruit_query <- input$search
    fruit_count <- plyr::count(fruit)
    colnames(fruit_count)[1] <- "fruit_type"
    fruit_count$fruit_type <- as.character(fruit_count$fruit_type)
    fruit_count <- merge(fruit_count, fruit_info, 
                               by = "fruit_type", all = T)
    fruit_count$freq <- ifelse(is.na(fruit_count$freq),
                               0, fruit_count$freq)
    searched_fruit <- fruit_count[fruit_count$fruit_type == fruit_query,]
    searched_fruit$freq <- round(searched_fruit$freq)
    return(searched_fruit)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: In a Shiny app, you could use `DT::renderDataTable` instead of `renderTable`, and function `formatRound`. Don't know if it works in the dashboard too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there, just replace:

```
searched_fruit$freq <- round(searched_fruit$freq)
```

with

```
searched_fruit$freq <- as.integer(searched_fruit$freq)
```

An alternatve would be to use `renderTable`s `digits` argument to change its default behaviour on numeric columns like this:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- renderTable({
    fruit_query <- input$search
    fruit_count <- plyr::count(fruit)
    colnames(fruit_count)[1] <- "fruit_type"
    fruit_count$fruit_type <- as.character(fruit_count$fruit_type)
    fruit_count <- merge(fruit_count, fruit_info, 
                         by = "fruit_type", all = T)
    fruit_count$freq <- ifelse(is.na(fruit_count$freq),
                               0, fruit_count$freq)
    searched_fruit <- fruit_count[fruit_count$fruit_type == fruit_query,]
  }, digits = 0)
}
```

Comment: That works, thank you! Do you know why as.integer() works but round() doesn't?

Comment: Using `round()` your column still remains numeric, so the default formatting option for numeric columns is used which is not the case with `as.integer()`. Another option would be to use as.character(round(myColumn, digits=x)) if you want to display a specific number of digits.